# Wordpress Social Login Facebook new user not register

Tags: wordpress, authentication, oauth-2.0

If you try to register with Facebook, it will help you with this error.

"An error occurred while creating a new user!"

https://sosyallog.com

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I have created a new account by canceling the app id and secret and have reached the solution in this way. friends who have trouble can finally try it. Thnk u.